# How do you change all values that are zero to another number?

Tags: r

I am trying to replace all zero entries with 0.001 in a single column. I've tried the following:

```
data7[data7$Time == 0,] <- 0.001
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If. it is a single column, we need

```
data7$Time[data7$Time == 0] <- 0.001
```

---

In the OP's code, it is replacing all the columns of the dataset by specifying the `,`

Answer (score 1):

And, as addition to @akrun's answer and for the sake of completeness, if you omit the comma in your example, it will replace all zeros in your data frame:

```r
data(iris)
x <- iris[1:10, ]

x$Sepal.Length[sample(1:nrow(x), 5)] <- 0
x$Sepal.Width[sample(1:nrow(x), 5)] <- 0
x$Petal.Length[sample(1:nrow(x), 5)] <- 0
x
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           0.0         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.9         0.0          0.0         0.2  setosa
#> 3           0.0         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4           0.0         3.1          0.0         0.2  setosa
#> 5           5.0         0.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6           5.4         0.0          0.0         0.4  setosa
#> 7           4.6         0.0          0.0         0.3  setosa
#> 8           0.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          0.0         0.2  setosa
#> 10          0.0         0.0          1.5         0.1  setosa

x[x == 0] <- Inf
x
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           Inf         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.9         Inf          Inf         0.2  setosa
#> 3           Inf         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4           Inf         3.1          Inf         0.2  setosa
#> 5           5.0         Inf          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6           5.4         Inf          Inf         0.4  setosa
#> 7           4.6         Inf          Inf         0.3  setosa
#> 8           Inf         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          Inf         0.2  setosa
#> 10          Inf         Inf          1.5         0.1  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>